# Отношения в Hibernate между тремя таблицами

Tags: hibernate, entity, relationship

подскажите пожалуйста как организовать, используя Jpa Hibertane, отношения когда есть 2 сущности "Language" не имеют отношений "Product" , а вот 3-ий класс "Description" имеет два первичный ключ от первых двух объектов, при этом не имея своего.

```
Спасибо большое.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вот какое решение нашел для себя

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    String name;
}

@Entity
public class Language {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    String description;
    String image;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "product_descr")
public class Descr {

    @Id
    Long id;
    private String descr;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private Product product;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private Language language;
}
```